# Is nested recursion possible or should we avoid recursion ?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, big-o

I came across a question like this

- F(1) = 1
- F(2n) = F(n)
- F(2n+1) = F(n) + F(n+1)

Develop a recursive program to compute `F`

Some user mentioned using two recursive function calls:

```
def calc(n):
  if n=1 :
    return 1
  else if(n%2)==0:
    return calc(n/2)
  else :
    return calc(n/2)+calc(n/2+1)  **NESTED RECURSION**
```

Is this a correct logic? Wouldn't the algorithm be exponentially large? 
I thought of a simple code like :

```
def calc(count):
  result[1]=1
  n=2
  for range(1,count):
      if n%2=0:
          result.append(result[n])
      else :
          result.append(result[n/2]+result[n/2+1])
  return result
```

Comment: `def calc(n):
  if … else:
    return calc(n/2)+calc(n/2+1)` that is not nested, just repeated. Try [Ackermann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both of these approaches are correct.  It is indeed legal to have multiple recursive calls from a function, and the meaning is what you'd think - just do one call, then the next, then the next, etc.

Interestingly, I don't think that the recursive version does make exponentially many calls.  It makes at most two recursive calls, but each are on a problem whose size is (approximately) half as large as the original call.  Essentially, the recurrence looks like this:

```
T(1) = 1
T(2) = 1
T(n) <= T(n / 2) + T(n / 2 + 1) + 1
```

I use "less than or equal to here" to say that in the best case you might just make one call, but in the worst case you make at most two.

I want to prove that this function T(n) <= max{cn + d, a} for some constants c, d, and a.  This would prove that T(n) = O(n) and thus makes at most linearly many calls.  As our base case, we have that

```
T(1) = 1
T(2) = 1
```

so let's set a = 1.  For the inductive step, we consider three cases.  First, let's consider when floor(n / 2) <= 2 and floor(n / 2 + 1) <= 2:

```
T(n) <= T(n / 2) + T(n / 2 + 1) + 1
     <= 1 + 1 + 1
     <= 3
```

If we assume that cn + d >= 3, when n = 3 or n = 4, then this works out correctly.  In particular, this means that 3c + d >= 3 and 4c + d >= 3.

In the next case, let's see what happens if floor(n / 2) <= 2 and floor(n / 2 + 1) >= 2.  Then we have that

```
T(n) <= T(n / 2) + T(n / 2 + 1) + 1
     <= 1 + max{c(n / 2 + 1) + d, 1} + 1
     <= 2 + max{c(n / 2 + 1) + d, 1}
     <= 3 + c(n / 2 + 1) + d
```

So if we have that 3 + c(n / 2 + 1) + d <= cn + d, this claim still holds.  Note that we're only in this case if n = 5, and so this means that we must have that

```
3 + c(n / 2 + 1) + d <= cn + d
3 + c(n / 2 + 1)     <= cn
3 + c(5 / 2 + 1)     <= 5c
3 + 5c/2 + c         <= 5c
3 + 7c/2             <= 5c
4                    <= 3c / 2
8 / 3                <= c
```

So we must have that c >= 8 / 3.

And finally, the case where neither n / 2 nor n / 2 + 1 are less than three:

```
T(n) <= T(n / 2) + T(n / 2 + 1) + 1
     <= c(n / 2) + d + c(n / 2 + 1) + d + 1
     <= cn / 2 + cn / 2 + c + 2d + 1
      = cn + c + 2d + 1
```

This is less than cn + d if

```
 cn + c + 2d + 1 <= cn + d
      c + 2d + 1 <=      d
      c +  d + 1 <= 0
```

This works if d = -c - 1.

From earlier, we know that 3c + d >= 3, which works if 2c - 1 >= 3, or 2c >= 4, so c >= 2.  We also have that 4c + d >= 3, which also works if c >= 2.  Letting c = 8 / 3, we get that d = -11 / 3, so

```
T(n) <= max{8n/3 - 11/3, 1}
```

So T(n) = O(n) and the recursion makes only linearly many calls.

---

The short version of this is that both the recursive and iterative versions take linear time.  Don't fear recursion's exponential-time blowup without being sure it's exponential. :-)  Though admittedtly, in this case, I really like the iterative version more.  It's clearer, more intuitive, and more immediately O(n).

Comment: What an explanation , I will read it for sure :) I am noob in this .

Comment: @Nishant- Here's hoping I didn't botch the math. :-)

Comment: @Paul Hankin- The value of F(n) might be no greater than n, but the time to compute it might be if we charge each recursive call a constant unit of time.  This recursive formulation (T(1) = 1, T(2n) = T(n) + 1, T(2n + 1) = T(n) + T(n + 1) + 1) can't easily be bounded by n.

Comment: Here, you forgot to distribute: 3 + c(5 / 2 + 1)     <= 5c, 3 + 5c/2 + 1         <= 5c.

Comment: @Dragontamer5788- Thanks for pointing this out; should be fixed now.

Comment: You screwed up again here:c(n / 2) + d + c(n / 2 + 1) + d + 1 <= cn / 2 + 2 + 2d.

Comment: @Dragontamer5788- D'oh, should be fixed up.  This required a bit of rewriting from the top, but I think it still works.

Comment: We can write a recursive version which takes O(Logn) time. See my answer.

Comment: @Moron- I'm still looking over it.  Independently, though, the point of my answer was mostly to show that you shouldn't necessarily assume that any branching recursion leads to an exponential-time solution.  I'll check out what you have in a sec.

Comment: @template: Maybe, but I mainly disagree with your last paragraph! The recursive solution I have is, IMO very intuitive (and faster) :-)

Comment: @Moron- I agree with you. :-)  But, given that this was directly more at the OP's two solutions and not the ideal solution missed in the post, I still stick with my story.

Comment: @template: Sure, I was also looking at the title :-)

Comment: To prove that the recursive version is O(n), it is probably easier to bound the depth of the recursion. This depth is `<= ceiling(log n) + 1`. So the tree has at most O(n) nodes.

Comment: @Chris Hopman- That is a really great technique.  I haven't seen it used before, mainly because it only works if the work done by each node is a constant and the branching factor is a constant.  However, I am definitely going to remember this in the future - I'm sure that this is going to come up again!

Answer (score 3):

Recursion isn't bad.  Think of recursion as a tool.  Some problems can be solved quite nicely with recursion (e.g. Fibonacci numbers), while other problems don't have a recursive bend (a worklist type algorithm).

Why people go awry with recursion is that they think a recursive solution will give them a good reputation.  I'd say, solve the problem with the simplest approach possible.

Sometimes that approach is recursion, sometimes it isn't.

Also, a recursive approach can be harder to understand.  So, you need to take readability into consideration.

Answer (score 3):

It is easier to estimate the performance of your second algorithm: it is clearly O(n) in space and time, with a small constant. But that does not mean the second algorithm is faster than the first. In fact it isn't!

In Python 2.6.5, your second algorithm is 25x *slower* than the first at calculating `calc(1000)`, 80x slower at calculating `calc(10000)`, and 1712x slower at calculating `calc(65535)`.

The worst-case behavior for the first algorithm, it seems, is for numbers like 54613 = 1101010101010101<sub>2</sub>. For that value, the first algorithm is only 16x faster than the second.

In the simple recursive algorithm, `calc(1000)` only involves 50 calls to `calc`, and even `calc(54613)` requires only 5166.

This O(log n) algorithm is faster still:

```
def C(x):
    a = 1
    b = 0
    # Loop invariant: we are going to return a*C(x) + b*C(x + 1).
    while x >= 2:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            a += b
        else:
            b += a
        x //= 2
    return a + b
```

The performance of this algorithm is easy to evaluate, but its correctness isn't. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can write a recursive version which is sublinear (O(log n)) in fact.

The key is to notice that you can compute *two* values for n and n+1 given the two values for [n/2] and [n/2]+1.

So if you think of the two values as *one* tuple T(n) = (F(n), F(n+1)), then given T([n/2]), you can compute T(n).

So your function will be something like

```
Tuple F(int n) {
    // Base cases:

    Tuple result;
    if (n is even) {
        Tuple t = F(n/2);
        result.First = t.First;
        result.Second =t.First + t.Second;

        return result;
    }

    if (n is odd) {

        Tuple t = F((n-1)/2);
        result.First = t.First + t.Second;
        result.Second = t.Second;
        return result;
    } 
}
```

This way you end up making just *one* recursive call and since you halve the size of input for each call, it is recursive *and* O(logn).

**Exercise**: Give an O(log n) time algorithm for Fibonacci numbers using this trick.

Hint: Use the identities:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The second sentence ("The key...") is unclear/incomplete. Your solution also requires the fact that you can calculate 2n + 2 from n and n + 1.